# Browser Console [Error]: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' from WebGL.js

Tags: ecmascript-6, three.js

I am following three.js documentation to create scene to show rotating box. A green rotating box was shown without issue following [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Creating-a-scene). But when I tried to include [WebGL compatibility check](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/WebGL-compatibility-check), code as shown below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="js/three.js"></script>
        <script src="js/WebGL.js"></script>

        <script>

            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
            var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            scene.add( cube );

            camera.position.z = 5;

            var animate = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
                cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            };

            if ( WEBGL.isWebGLAvailable() ) {

            // Initiate function or other initializations here
            animate();

            } else {

            var warning = WEBGL.getWebGLErrorMessage();
            document.getElementById( 'container' ).appendChild( warning );

            }


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

, browser console shows error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' from [WebGL.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/jsm/WebGL.js).

There isn't any issue threads in three.js Github about it. I wonder what could be the issue? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error states `error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'`, meaning that the JavaScript parser failed. It's not a Three.js error.

According to your link [WebGL compatibility check](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/WebGL-compatibility-check), the code you imported is a JavaScript ES module.
Take a look at [this line](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/jsm/WebGL.js#L98). This line uses the `export` keyword, used to export a module. Thus, you are dealing with a module here and not a classic JS script.

If you want to include a module and not a simple script, you need to use:

```
<script src="js/three.js"></script>
<script type="module">
  import { WebGL } from 'js/WebGL.js';
  if ( WEBGL.isWebGLAvailable() ) {
    // ...
  }
</script>
```

You can also directly use the WebGL script file instead of the JS module, if that's easier for you. You can find it [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/jsm/WebGL.js).
Then, you should be able to access the `WEBGL` namespace like that:

```
if ( THREE.WEBGL.isWebGLAvailable() ) {

  // WebGL is available

} else {

  // WebGL isn't available :(

}
```

I would recommend that you read the difference between a JS script and modules. For instance [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and explanation, the error is gone. Currently I am resolving CORS errors by including the js code in reactjs local server.

Comment: You should maybe mark your question as resolved then?